# Formar um dataframe a partir de 3

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho 3 arquivos CSV com 3 data frames, sendo que um traz as colunas `países` e `população`, outro traz `países` e `área` e outro traz `países` e `expectativa de vida`. No primeiro, são 195 registros, no segundo, 194 e no terceiro, 187.

Preciso conseguir formar um data frame apenas com `países`, `população`, `área` e `expectativa de vida`, mas, para isso, quero pegar apenas os países que aparecem nos 3 data frames e que as outras colunas sejam preenchidas com os registros respectivos a cada país.

Answer (score 3):

A função `left_join` do pacote `dplyr` faz exatamente o que é pedido. Entretanto, ela só funciona com dois data frames de cada vez, então ela precisa ser aplicada em duas oportunidades.

Assumindo que os data frames se chamam `df1`, `df2` e `df3`, faça

```
library(dplyr)
df_final <- left_join(left_join(df1, df2), 
                      df3)
```

Answer (score 2):

## R base

Uma solução só em R base pode ser com `Reduce/merge`.

Primeiro, ler os ficheiros. Estas duas instruções partem do princípio que os únicos ficheiros que estão no diretório atual com a extensão `"csv"` são os três ficheiros que interessam.

Se os dados tiverem a vírgula como ponto decimal, usar `read.csv`.

```
ficheiros <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv")
list_df <- lapply(ficheiros, read.csv)
```

Agora juntar os ficheiros.

```
dados <- Reduce(function(x, y){merge(x, y, by = "paises", all = FALSE)}, list_df)
```

Como o `merge` utiliza por defeito as colunas com nomes comuns e só combina as linhas com valores comuns, o código acima pode ser simplificado.

```
Reduce(merge, list_df)
```

## Pacote `dplyr`

Depois de ver a [resposta do Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447109/82237), reparei que `Reduce` também pode ser aplicado ao problema de juntar (`merge` ou `join`) várias bases. Mas para só ter as linhas com países comuns, `inner_join` parece ser a opção correta.

```
library(dplyr)

Reduce(inner_join, list_df)
```

**Dados de teste**

```
df1 <- data.frame(paises = letters[1:4], X = 1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(paises = letters[1:5], Y = 5:1)
df3 <- data.frame(paises = letters[c(1,2,4)], Z = rnorm(3))

list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df"))
```